# How to include php file in php variable string?

Tags: php

**Solution:** This question was asked when I had little knowledge in web-development, anyway the answer to this question can be found here: [How to assign the contents of a file to a variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230280/how-to-assign-the-contents-of-a-file-to-a-variable-in-php).

I have tried in may different ways, but I can not understand how I can include an external PHP file in my php variable. Sorry for asking such a simple question, thanks in advance!

```
$searchbar = ' 
<!--Left box for platenumber search engine-->                     
  <div class="sections">
    <div class="leftpart">
         <div class = "platenumbertop">
                        <!--Textfield-->
                        <ul class = "searchname">QUICK SEARCH</ul>
                        <!--Content-->
                        <div class = "platenumbercontent">
                         hellooooo<br>
                         hellooooo<br> 

                         -----INLUDE PHP FILE HERE, HOW?-------

                         hellooooo<br>
                         hellooooo<br>  

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

code continues...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the output of a php file in a string, the easiest option is to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();?>
<!--Left box for platenumber search engine-->                     
  <div class="sections">
    <div class="leftpart">
         <div class = "platenumbertop">
              <!--Textfield-->
              <ul class = "searchname">QUICK SEARCH</ul>
               <!--Content-->
               <div class = "platenumbercontent">
                    hellooooo<br>
                    hellooooo<br> 

                    <?php include 'file.php';?>

                    hellooooo<br>
                    hellooooo<br>  

                 </div>
              </div>
<?php $searchbar = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("test.txt"); 
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp

For your question:

```
 <?php
    $contents = file_get_contents("test.txt"); 
    ?>
$searchbar = ' 
<!--Left box for platenumber search engine-->                     
  <div class="sections">
    <div class="leftpart">
         <div class = "platenumbertop">
                        <!--Textfield-->
                        <ul class = "searchname">QUICK SEARCH</ul>
                        <!--Content-->
                        <div class = "platenumbercontent">
                         hellooooo<br>
                         hellooooo<br> 

                        '.$contents.'

                         hellooooo<br>
                         hellooooo<br>  

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: As the question says **php** file, then this is unlikely to be a solution - this would append the source code, not the output

Answer (score 0):

The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file. You cannot include an external PHP file to php variable. You can read entire file into a string

```
$searchbar = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```